# Suppose we have a polynomial over the integers with a non-zero leading coefficient over mod p.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-factorization

Suppose we have a polynomial over the integers with a non-zero leading coefficient over $\mod p$.
Suppose $r$ is a zero of $f(r)$ is congruent to $0 \mod p$, show there exists polynomial $g(x)$ such that $(x-r)(g(x)) = a_nx^n..+a_1x +b_o$ where $a_0$ is congruent to $b_0 \mod p$.

This is what I have so far, since $f(r)=0$, then I know I can write $f(x)=(x-r)(g(x))$.

I know (by doing an example, that the product of $r$ and $b_0$ is gonna be congruent to $a_0 \mod p$. But that's all I have so far. Can anyone help?

Comment: An essentially complete proof was given to a very similar question of yours on Nov. 9.  We do not quite have $f(x)=(x-t)g(x)$. It is actually $f(x)=(x-r)g(x)+c$ where $c\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Then let $b_0=a_0-c$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas unfortunately I cannot see how this shows there's a polynomial with those conditions

Comment: I have added some detail to the original answer,  If there remain points of difficulty, please leave a message.